# MongoDB aggregate nested filed max value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this collection:

```json
{ "_id" : { "carrier_nam" : "Alaska Airlines Inc.", "airport_nam" : "Kodiak, AK: Kodiak Airport" }, "value" : { "security2" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "carrier_nam" : "Alaska Airlines Inc.", "airport_nam" : "Santa Ana, CA: John Wayne Airport-Orange County" }, "value" : { "security2" : 29 } }
{ "_id" : { "carrier_nam" : "JetBlue Airways", "airport_nam" : "Baltimore, MD: Baltimore/Washington International Thurgood Marshall" }, "value" : { "security2" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : { "carrier_nam" : "ATA Airlines d/b/a ATA", "airport_nam" : "Denver, CO: Denver International" }, "value" : { "security2" : 5 } }
```

I need to get the max value of `security2` delays and get the "airport_nam" value that is associated with the max value of the `carrier_nam`.

This aggregation result gets me the correct answer, but unfortunately, I can't also print the "airport_nam" filed that `security2` happened the must in it.

this is the aggregation that gets me the correct answer without the "airport_nam".

```
db.tmp2.aggregate([{ $group: { "_id": "$_id.carrier_nam", value: { $max: "$value" } } }
   , { $out : "tmp22"  }
])
```

This is the result (without the "airport_nam" that associated with the nested obj key that i need to add):

```json
{ "_id" : "Northwest Airlines Inc.", "value" : { "security2" : 78 } }
{ "_id" : "Independence Air", "value" : { "security2" : 15 } }
{ "_id" : "AirTran Airways Corporation", "value" : { "security2" : 0 } }
```

for better understanding the final answer should be like this:

```json
{ "_id" : "Northwest Airlines Inc.", "value" : { "security2" : 78 },"airport_nam" : "Kinston }
{ "_id" : "Independence Air", "value" : { "security2" : 15 } }
{ "_id" : "AirTran Airways Corporation", "value" : { "security2" : 0 },"airport_nam" : "Denver}
```

How can I add the "airport_nam" to the aggregation final answer without using him in the group?

The current structure gets me the correct answer, I just need to print by her side the "airport_nam" nested field.

thanks to the helpers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$max` with argument document not just a single value.
Just put the value you want to compare as first field,comparison on the second field will happen only if first field equal

[See how mongodb compares things](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/)

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.carrier_nam",
      "value": {
        "$max": {
          "security2": "$value.security2",
          "airport_nam": "$_id.airport_nam"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "airport_nam": "$value.airport_nam",
      "carrier_nam": "$_id",
      "value": {
        "security2": "$value.security2"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Run code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ydk7Eb6GZA8)

If something doesn't work, if you can give more data, and how you want them to become.